# Question about universal quantifier and logic formula

Tags: logic

If I have $(\forall u: F(u,v))\implies G(v)$

I can  say $(\forall u)[F(u,v)\implies G(v)]$?

Comment: Some similar issues are discussed in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/589797/26306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily -- the first does not imply the second in general. To see this, let the domain be the integers, $G(v)$ be always false (say, "$v$ is strictly between 0 and 1"), and $F(u,v)$ be "$u$ is even".  Then your first line is true (not all integers are even, so the hypothesis is false), but the second is false, as one can see by taking $u=2$.

Comment: ok thanks, in general is not true, I'm working with the following sentence:

$(\forall u: a(u,v)=0)\implies v=0$

where $a$ is a bilinear form, and I'd like that $a(v,v)=0 \implies v=0$ taking in particular $u=v$ , is this posible?

Comment: Isn't $a((u_1,u_2), (v_1, v_2)) = u_1v_1 - u_2v_2$ a counterexample?

Comment: if $a$ is positive definite, this must be true?

Comment: Yes, by definition if $a$ is positive definite then $a(u,u) > 0$ when $u\neq 0$.